# How to read an inputText in Ui.R and filter that data in a CSV file to make a Wordcloud

Tags: r, textinput, sqldf, word-cloud

I have to show a WordCloud in R with text filtered with sql query and get a parameter by user with Textinput.

How can I read a Textinput on ui.R, process a query with this value in global.R and show a wordcloud in Server.R ?

I have 3 files: ui.R, global.R and Server.R

My Ui.R contains this code:

```
library(tm)
library(wordcloud)
library(memoise)
library(sqldf)
library(shiny)
        shinyUI(fluidPage(

          books <<- list("Descritores FOUSP" = "descritor"),

          Application title
          titlePanel("CRAI"),

          headerPanel(title="Pesquisa de Descritores"),
          sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel(

              selectInput("selection", "Escolha livro:",
                          choices = books),
              br(),
              h5('Qual é o tema da sua pesquisa ?'),


              textInput("descritor", "Digite um descritor","") 
    ## I input a parameter here !!!!  

            ),

              mainPanel (

                textOutput("desc"),
                textOutput("result")

                        )
                )
          )
        )
```

In my global.R, I have a code to read a CSV file, and I made a query in SQLDF to filter data. But I need to filter based on inputText from Ui.R file. I wrote this code:

```
library(tm)
library(wordcloud)
library(memoise)
library(sqldf)

# The list of valid books
books <<- list("Descritores FOUSP" = "descritor")

# Using "memoise" to automatically cache the results
getTermMatrix <- memoise(function(book) {
  # Careful not to let just any name slip in here; a
  # malicious user could manipulate this value.
  if (!(book %in% books))
    stop("Unknown book")

  csv <- read.csv2("TesesFOResumo.csv", colClasses = "character")


  #sql

  output$desc <- renderText(input$descritor)
  sql <- sprintf("SELECT * FROM csv WHERE %s < 100", output$desc)
  #sql

  output$result <- renderText(sql)

  # Filtrar pela palavra chave escolhida e pegar os sysnos que fazem parte dos assuntos
  # query1  <-  sqldf("select sysno from outcome where Assuntos LIKE '%remocao lingua%' ")
  #query1

 sql1 <- sqldf("SELECT Assuntos FROM csv as O1 WHERE sysno IN (select sysno from csv as O2 where Assuntos LIKE '%câncer_língua%' AND O1.sysno = O2.sysno) ")
 #sql1




  ##sqldf("select Assuntos, sysno from outcome O3 where [Resumo.em.português] LIKE '%laser%' UNION ALL 
  ##    select Assuntos, sysno from outcome O1 where sysno in (select sysno from outcome O2 where assuntos LIKE '%laser%')")

  text <- sqldf("select Assuntos from outcome O3 where [Resumo.em.português] LIKE '%câncer_língua%' UNION ALL 
                select Assuntos from outcome O1 where sysno in (select sysno from outcome O2 where assuntos LIKE '%câncer_língua%')")



  myCorpus = Corpus(VectorSource(sql1))
  myCorpus = tm_map(myCorpus, content_transformer(tolower))
  myCorpus = tm_map(myCorpus, removePunctuation)
  myCorpus = tm_map(myCorpus, removeNumbers)
  myCorpus = tm_map(myCorpus, removeWords,
                    c(stopwords("SMART"), "de", "da", "dos", "the", "and", "but"))

  myDTM = TermDocumentMatrix(myCorpus,
                             control = list(minWordLength = 1))

  m = as.matrix(myDTM)

  sort(rowSums(m), decreasing = TRUE)
  ####




  myCorpus2 = Corpus(VectorSource(text))
  myCorpus2 = tm_map(myCorpus2, content_transformer(tolower))
  myCorpus2 = tm_map(myCorpus2, removePunctuation)
  myCorpus2 = tm_map(myCorpus2, removeNumbers)
  myCorpus2 = tm_map(myCorpus2, removeWords,
                    c(stopwords("SMART"), "thy", "thou", "thee", "the", "and", "but"))

  myDTM2 = TermDocumentMatrix(myCorpus2,
                             control = list(minWordLength = 1))

  m2 = as.matrix(myDTM2)

  sort(rowSums(m2), decreasing = TRUE)

  #wordcloud(myCorpus2, colors=brewer.pal(8,"Dark2"),random.order=FALSE)



})
```

And I want to show the WordCloud from results of Query.

My Server.R is here. I know how to show the wordcloud, but not with query results.

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$desc <- renderText(input$descritor)
  output$result <- renderText(sql)



})
```